# iexpress console parameters

Tags: command-line, parameters, iexpress

I need create one .exe file from a few dll and .exe files. I used iexpress. Program works fine but I can't transmit parameters in console because program  runs from console. How can I transmit parameters in console and run my application with these parameters?

Like this:
     gm convert -size 100x100 a.jpg b.pdf

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `/c` switch to do this, eg:

```
gm /c:"convert -size 100x100 a.jpg b.pdf"
```

(assuming that `convert.exe` is the name of the executable inside the IExpress file `gm.exe`)